# Ruby on rails tutorial NoMethodError in MessagesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm following the official ROR tutorial at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and I am stuck at section 5.7 which is going to show the articles. In my code i use message instead of articles.
The following are my controller and new.html.erb

**`Controller code`**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @messages = Msg4me.all
  end

  def show
    @message = Msg4me.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @message = Msg4me.new(message_params)

    @message.save
    redirect_to @message
  end

  private
  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:title, :text)
  end

end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<p>IT's <%= Time.now %> now</p>
<p>Leave me a message below</p>
<%= form_for :message,url: messages_path do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :title %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.label :text %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :text %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

**`routes.rb`**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get "homepage" => "homepage#hello"
      resources :messages

      root :to => "homepage#hello"
    end
```

i have a error which is

> NoMethodError in MessagesController#create
>   undefined method `msg4me_url' for # 
>   MessagesController:0x000000076248a8

What's wrong with this error? I have thought about it for a long time and couldn't solve it.

Comment: Do you have a `Msg4me` model defined? I think - according to the controller name and routing configuration - it should be `Message`.

Comment: yes i have a msg4me.rb in models. So  i should change my 'msg4me.rb' to 'messages.rb' ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def new
   @message = Msg4me.new
end
```

**`new.html.erb`**

```
<p>IT's <%= Time.now %> now</p>
 <p>Leave me a message below</p>
 <%= form_for (:message,url: messages_path) do |f| %>
   <p>
     <%= f.label :title %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :title %>
   </p>

   <p>
     <%= f.label :text %><br>
     <%= f.text_area :text %>
   </p>

   <p>
     <%= f.submit %>
   </p>
<% end %>
```